# Php Javascript Youtube API error

Tags: javascript, php, youtube-api

I've got this code, which add videos (and videos infos) of a YouTube channel ($_POST) on a div of the Html code :

```
    var args= "url="+urlchaine;
    xhr_object.open("POST", "traitement.php", true);
xhr_object.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    if(xhr_object.readyState == 4) {
            eval(xhr_object.responseText);
        }
        return xhr_object.readyState;
}
xhr_object.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr_object.send(args);
```

traitement.php :

```
<?php
 if ( isset($_POST["url"]) && !empty($_POST["url"]) )
$urlchaine = $_POST["url"];
 else
$urlchaine = null;

 $stringresult = str_replace("http://www.youtube.com/user/", "",$urlchaine);

 require_once "Zend/Loader.php";
 Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_YouTube');
 $yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
 //Get Video info with channel name $stringresult
 $videoFeed = $yt->getVideoFeed('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/...');

 if ( $stringresult != null){
  echo "var mydiv = document.getElementById('vids');";
  echo "var newcontent = document.createElement('div');";

  foreach ($videoFeed as $v): $thumbs = $v->getVideoThumbnails();
    $videoId = $v->getVideoId();
    $thumb = $thumbs[0]['url'];
    $videoViewCount = $v->getVideoViewCount();
    $videoTitle = $v->getVideoTitle();
echo "newcontent.innerHTML = 
 '<div class=\"videos\">' +
 ' <div class=\"img_videos\">' +
 '  <img class=\"img_video\" width=\"250\" idvideo=\"".$videoId."\" ' +
 '  src=\"".$thumb."\"/>' +
 ' </div>' +
 ' <h3>$videoTitle</h3>' +
 ' <p>$videoViewCount views</p>' +
 '</div>' ;";
echo "mydiv.appendChild(newcontent.firstChild);";
endforeach;
?>
```

The problem is, when I want to do that, it works perfectly with some channels, whereas an error has existed for others (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier). After several tests, I saw that by removing the display of $ videoTitle, every channels test worked. What is wrong with my code? O.o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$videoTitle` seems to contains a simple quote in somes cases, which break your JS code.

Try escaping this quotes with something like this :

```
str_replace("'", "&sbquo;", $videoTitle)
```